# How to pass Single EditText multuple value in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, multiple-value

I want to Pass the multiple value of EditText in the Intent as String []. Please Help me out. Thank You.

Here Below image shows the multiple value of single EditText.
 [image: multiple value in single EditText]

Here I am added my android code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QResultDetail.class);
           String[] category = new String[](etSelectCategory.getText().toString());// Here i am getting error
            i.putExtra("city", etSelectCity.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("category", category);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btQSearch) {
                //Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(), city_list.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: String category = etSelectCategory.getText().toString

Comment: String[] categotys = category.split(",");

Comment: String category1 = categotys[0];

Comment: String category2 = categotys[1];

Comment: Then putExtra category1 and category2

Comment: dear why you not pass just string. intent..? just pass string then where you want to get in that activity make array using split

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen Trung Hieu.. Now ,I have gotten that i want..